# Dynamic Django models.TextField() value

Tags: python, django

Is it possible for a Django TextField to have templatetag variable as a value and then make it dynamic during the template render?

models.py

```
class EmailNotification(models.Model):
    status = models.TextField() 
    greetings = models.TextField()
    message = models.TextField()
```

value of status in the django admin is: "I am number {{ count }}"

value of greetings in the django admin is: "Hi My name is {{ name }}"

value of message in the django admin is: "I am {{ age }}"

Is it possible to render these values in a django template and instead of a string output with those templatetag variables, the templatetag variables will return a dynamic value coming from a dictionary context

Comment: That's really not possible, nor it is a good way of being dynamic. Even if it's possible, what if you change your variable name? You have to change it in admin and template as well, which is error-prone. You should only render the `EmailNotification` field values `as is` in the template, then feed it with django context.

Comment: Hi Shang Wang, I actually found an answer by myself written below but thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a solution myself and for those who might find this helpful, please see code below

```
from django.template import Context, Template

def email_check(request):
    template = 'variables_inside_model_text_field.html'
    x = "Hi My name is {{ name }}"
    t = Template(x)
    c = Context({'name': 'Dean Christian Armada'})
    html = t.render(c)
    context_dict = {}
    context_dict['html'] = html
    return render(request, template, context_dict)
```

Will result to : "Hi My name is Dean Christian Armada" in the template